# have an android error with a game

Tags: java, android

Okay guys,my problem is that..all i want is that..where the user touch with the finger,there the spaceship will go in my game,which is in portrait game.

```
int a = player.getX();    
int b = player.getY();

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            a = (int) event.getX();
            b = (int) event.getY();
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I tried that..but it is giving me java.NullPointerException or something like that at: int a = player.getX();
    int b = player.getY();
Player is the class of the playership and those methods take the x and y of the ship,the position.

Comment: `player` is null at the time `player.getX()` is called.  Can you show how you're trying to initialize `player`?

Comment: yes i think this is the problem..now i am in class SSView(SpaceShip class i mean),here after the declaration of the class i initialize that:

Comment: private PlayerShip player;

Comment: and in the constructor of the class,(SSview),that:player = new PlayerShip(context, x, y);

Comment: thank you so much,now i dont have any error..just that the spaceship isn't actually going where i put my finger :)) any ideas about that...maybe is a problem here: @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x = (int) event.getX();
                y = (int) event.getY();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

Comment: @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x = (int) event.getX();
                y = (int) event.getY();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

Answer (score 0):

In the comments section above, you mention that `player` is initialized in the constructor.  The problem is that these 2 lines are executed *before* the constructor is run.

```
int a = player.getX();    
int b = player.getY();
```

Change these to just `int a;` and `int b;`, then initialize these values in your constructor after you initialize `player`.

```
public MyConstructor(...) {

    player = new PlayerShip(...);

    a = player.getX();
    b = player.getY();
}
```

Comment: yes but...if then i use a and b in another function,will that function see their values?i mean in the onTouchEvent() function

Comment: @roby2070 The constructor will be executed first, so yes.

Comment: i mean..the ship is not actually moving

Comment: @roby2070 That's a different problem, and there's not enough to go on in your original question.  I encourage you to create a new question for that with all of the relevant code.

Comment: I am a beginner so i do not have questions anymore,anyway if you have any others ideas,i'd like to hear them